# Bluetooth keeps crashing while trying to Advertise via BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

in my app I use advertising and scanning via BLE. Advertising is done every minute for 10 seconds, scanning is done for 1 minute every 5 minutes. Occasionally I see an error that says `Bluetooth keeps stopping` or something similar. From what I noticed, when it happens it happens on Samsung A50 and Samsung A30 devices.
This is the crash log that I see. Is there a way I can solve this problem?

```
2020-06-15 09:52:30.931 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2020-06-15 09:52:30.931 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/a30dd/a30:9/PPR1.180610.011/A305FDDU0ASA9:user/release-keys'
2020-06-15 09:52:30.931 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '3'
2020-06-15 09:52:30.932 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2020-06-15 09:52:30.932 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG: pid: 19690, tid: 19742, name: btu message loo  >>> com.android.bluetooth <<<
2020-06-15 09:52:30.932 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xb1150008
2020-06-15 09:52:30.932 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     x0  00000000b1150000  x1  000000789e83a140  x2  000000789edfa780  x3  00000078a0acd110
2020-06-15 09:52:30.932 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     x4  000f27c43f000000  x5  00000000ffffffff  x6  0000007942ed1000  x7  00000000000df992
2020-06-15 09:52:30.932 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     x8  0000000000010002  x9  00000078a0acd3e0  x10 0000000000000001  x11 0000000000000017
2020-06-15 09:52:30.932 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     x12 0000000000000018  x13 000000005ee71aae  x14 002bde7294f34880  x15 0000507d9e75301e
2020-06-15 09:52:30.932 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     x16 00000078a12a85b8  x17 00000078a11c76cc  x18 0000000000000001  x19 000000789f47b450
2020-06-15 09:52:30.932 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     x20 000000789e83a140  x21 000000789edfb588  x22 000000789f47b45d  x23 00000078a12ac000
2020-06-15 09:52:30.933 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     x24 000000789edfb588  x25 000000789edfb588  x26 000000789edfa598  x27 000000789edfad18
2020-06-15 09:52:30.933 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     x28 0000000000002019  x29 000000789edfa4d0
2020-06-15 09:52:30.933 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     sp  000000789edfa470  lr  00000078a11d290c  pc  00000078a09ce54c
2020-06-15 09:52:30.988 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2020-06-15 09:52:30.988 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000000002b854c  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (btu_hcif_command_complete_evt_with_cb_on_task(BT_HDR*, void*) [clone .cfi]+176)
2020-06-15 09:52:30.988 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0000000000096908  /system/lib64/libchrome.so (base::debug::TaskAnnotator::RunTask(char const*, base::PendingTask*)+248)
2020-06-15 09:52:30.988 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00000000000afd14  /system/lib64/libchrome.so (base::MessageLoop::RunTask(base::PendingTask*)+416)
2020-06-15 09:52:30.988 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00000000000affbc  /system/lib64/libchrome.so (base::MessageLoop::DeferOrRunPendingTask(base::PendingTask)+52)
2020-06-15 09:52:30.989 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00000000000b03f8  /system/lib64/libchrome.so (base::MessageLoop::DoWork()+380)
2020-06-15 09:52:30.989 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00000000000b1790  /system/lib64/libchrome.so (base::MessagePumpDefault::Run(base::MessagePump::Delegate*)+180)
2020-06-15 09:52:30.989 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 00000000000afa08  /system/lib64/libchrome.so (base::MessageLoop::RunHandler()+112)
2020-06-15 09:52:30.989 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 00000000000cc60c  /system/lib64/libchrome.so (base::RunLoop::Run()+136)
2020-06-15 09:52:30.989 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00000000002b88c8  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (btu_message_loop_run(void*) [clone .cfi]+324)
2020-06-15 09:52:30.989 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 000000000032f398  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (work_queue_read_cb(void*) [clone .cfi]+120)
2020-06-15 09:52:30.989 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 000000000032d840  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (run_reactor(reactor_t*, int) [clone .cfi]+416)
2020-06-15 09:52:30.989 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 000000000032d674  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (reactor_start(reactor_t*) [clone .cfi]+84)
2020-06-15 09:52:30.990 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 000000000032f148  /system/lib64/libbluetooth.so (run_thread(void*) [clone .cfi]+188)
2020-06-15 09:52:30.990 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 00000000000836c8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+196)
2020-06-15 09:52:30.990 20332-20332/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 0000000000023bac  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

This is how I start and stop advertising:

```
public void stopAdvertise() {


        if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            if(advertiser == null)
                advertiser = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser(); // if we turned the bluetooth on while the service is running

            if(advertiser != null)
                advertiser.stopAdvertising(advertiseCallback);

            mEventListenerCallback.onEvent(ADVERTISING_STATUS, false);
        }
    }

    public void startAdvertise(String serviceUUID) {

        if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if(advertiser == null)
                advertiser = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser(); // if we turned the bluetooth on while the service is running

            Config config = Config.getInstance(mContext);

            ParcelUuid pUuid = new ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString(serviceUUID));

            AdvertiseData.Builder dataBuilder = new AdvertiseData.Builder();
            dataBuilder.addServiceUuid(pUuid);
            dataBuilder.setIncludeDeviceName(false);
            dataBuilder.setIncludeTxPowerLevel(true);

            int currentTime = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
            byte[] key = CryptoManager.getInstance(mContext).mySelf.generateEphemeralId(currentTime, BLEScannerManager.sGeoHash);

            dataBuilder.addServiceData(pUuid, key);

            AdvertiseSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder();
            settingsBuilder.setAdvertiseMode(config.getAdvertiseMode());
            settingsBuilder.setTimeout((int) config.getAdvertiseDuration());
            settingsBuilder.setTxPowerLevel(config.getAdvertiseTXPowerLevel());
            settingsBuilder.setConnectable(false);

            if(advertiser != null)
                advertiser.startAdvertising(settingsBuilder.build(), dataBuilder.build(), advertiseCallback);
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How can I solve this. How can I know what exactly causing the bluetooth to crash. The log is not very informative.

Comment: You should inform Samsung about the crash if you can't get this issue on non-Samsung devices.